# Conditional expectation of negatively associated random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

If $X$ and $Y$ are negatively associated random variables both with support $\{0,1,\dots,n \}$, can I conclude that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X | Y = i] \ge \mathbb{E}[X | Y = i+1]$$

Comment: Depends on what you mean by negatively associated. What does that mean to you?

Comment: Ah. Maybe I should have clarified. [This is what I am referring to](https://cs.cmu.edu/~dwajc/notes/Negative%20Association.pdf).
A set of random variables $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n$ is said to be negatively
associated (NA) if for any two disjoint index sets $I, J \subseteq [n]$ and two functions $f, g$ both monotone increasing
or both monotone decreasing, it holds
$$E[f(X_i: i \in I) \cdot g(Xj : j \in J)] \le E[f(X_i: i \in I)] \cdot E[g(X_j : j \in J)$$

Comment: The notation $f(X_i\ :\ i\in I)$ suggests that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^{|I|}$ for some $I\subset[n]$, in which case it is not clear what it means for $f$ to be monotone increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @Math1000 I think you mean $I \in [n]$ and not $I \subset [n]$. Can you clarify what is unclear?

Comment: It's unclear because you left out part of the definition; the functions $f,g$ are defined on $\mathbb R^n$ and are both monotone *in their respective indices*.